# trim white space and return keywords in lua

Tags: lua

I need to trim white spaces in string and for each word between white spaces return key words in the table
I tried own code but doesn't work fine

`string ="happy halloween day"`

```
local function trimSpace(value)
   if value then
     local tags={}
     i=0
     for c in value:gmatch("%s") do
       i= i + 1
       local c = value:sub(i,i)
      tags[#tags+1] = {"tag" = c}
      end
     return tags
   end
end

local tag = trimSpace(string)
```

Comment: Post the result you are expecting as well.

Comment: anyway errors: 1) don't use keyword `string` as variable, 2) `{["tag"] = c}`

Comment: all variables and tables names in this case just for example.i just what any body give me code to trim space and return keywords in array

like this `tags.tag[1] = happy ,  tags.tag[2] = halloween `

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this function is "split" with spaces as separator:

```
local s = "happy halloween day"
local function Split(s)
    local t ={}
    for word in s:gmatch("([^%s]+)") do
         t[#t+1] = {["tag"] =  word }
    end
    return t
end

local tags =Split(s)
for k,v in pairs(tags) do
   print(k,v.tag)
end
```